# In Python, how to check if Selenium WebDriver has quit or not?

Tags: python, selenium

Following is the sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

(The window gets closed due to some reason here)

```
driver.quit()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 183, in quit
>       RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 592, in quit
>       self.execute(Command.QUIT)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 297, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Tried to run
>   command without establishing a connection

**Is there some way to check if an instance of webdriver is active?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this which uses psutil

```
from selenium import webdriver
import psutil

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://tarunlalwani.com")

driver_process = psutil.Process(driver.service.process.pid)

if driver_process.is_running():
    print ("driver is running")

    firefox_process = driver_process.children()
    if firefox_process:
        firefox_process = firefox_process[0]

        if firefox_process.is_running():
            print("Firefox is still running, we can quit")
            driver.quit()
        else:
            print("Firefox is dead, can't quit. Let's kill the driver")
            firefox_process.kill()
    else:
        print("driver has died")
```

Comment: this is a good answer, except it would fail to close the browser in the case where the service has already died (for whatever reason) and it left an orphaned browser running.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, do you mean that the geckodriver itself died? This would only work if you capture the PID as soon the driver is created and if you are not able to capture the same you will anyway have not to kill it. Only other option would be to kill all `firefox.exe`, which may not be a good way to kill

Answer (score 6):

be Pythonic... try to quit and catch the exception if it fails.

```
try:
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I figured out and liked:

```
def setup(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.Firefox()

def teardown(self):
    # self.wd.service.process == None if quit already.
    if self.wd.service.process != None:
        self.wd.quit()
```

Note: `driver_process=psutil.Process(driver.service.process.pid)` will throw exception if driver already quits.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [Corey Golberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909741/6831393) is the correct way.

However if you really need to look under the hood, the `driver.service.process` property gives access to the underlying Popen object that manages the open browser. If the process has quit, the `process` property will be `None` and testing whether it is truthy will identify the state of the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# your code where the browser quits

if not driver.service.process:
    print('Browser has quit unexpectedly')

if driver.service.process:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Corey Goldberg's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909741/18809168) and to [scign's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072690/18809168):

Don't forget the import:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
```

Also, in Corey's answer, the code will hang for about 10sec while attempting to close an already closed webdriver before moving to the except clause.